# ffmpeg Proper Command to Upscale Video

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, x264, encoder

We have a problem with the watermark upon ffmpeg conversion to .mp4.

We use a  PHP KVS tube script, running CentOS & hopefully the latest ffmpeg version.

If input video is in smaller resolution then watermark appearing in the output is too big, so video won't properly re-size (upscale).

Looking for a proper command that will upscale video resolution if this is smaller than 720px (width). Re sizing bigger videos work fine, but not smaller.

So, we would always like 720px-1(dynamic height), no matter what is the input video resolution.

Here is one of the command we have tried to use but it didnt work can you please provide the correct command to upscale videos 720px (width).

---

This is the below command which we used but it has not worked
**_______________________________________________________**-

-vf "resize=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -f mp4

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the `scale` filter:

```
-vf "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -f mp4
```

because I'm not sure that ffmpeg has a video filter `resize` !